# Problems scheduling jobs with spring crontrigger

Tags: spring, tomcat6, quartz-scheduler

I'm facing a quite strange behavior of my application. I have an application that uses Spring3 and runs over tomcat6 and it schedules jobs through spring's crontrigger.

My cron expression is "0 0 3 * * ?", which should fire my job every 3am (once a day). My application (and my jobs) were working fine until yesterday. This night the things went crazy, and my job starter working continuously. It was like that the runtime were ignoring the cron expression, and started executing my job in an infinite loop.

Does this make any sense to any of you?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your job was throwing an exception, rather than completing gracefully, so Quartz re-executed it (again, and again).